# Does the Greek Type D visa let me enter any Schengen country?

Tags: schengen, long-stay-visas, schengen-visas

Actually I have type D multiple entry visa issued by Greece and valid for 3 months. I'm a little bit confused: is it a Schengen visa? Does it allow me to enter the Schengen area?

I have been emailing many EU embassies: some say I can travel with that visa, some say I can't, and that I have to get another visa to visit the Schengen area. What is the correct answer?